# How can I use .splice() when trying to delete/remove specific strings in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've created a successful way of removing the strings in an array, but is there a way to remove specific parts in an array using .splice()

```
const arr = [1000, 2000, "numbers", 5000, 6000, "integers"];

getInt = (arr) => {
  return arr.map((i)=> {if (/^\d+$/.test(i))
   return i;
  });
}
getInt(arr);

console.log(getInt(arr));
```

Comment: Sorry if my code is confusing, I just started learning javascript.

Comment: You want to remove all strings from that array or just one string - the first match?

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1000, 2000, "numbers", 5000, 6000, "integers"];

console.log(arr.filter(item =>  Number.isInteger(item)))
```

You can use filter method to filter out the integers, give it a try mate.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, It's easier to understand for me because I just started learning JavaScript 3 days ago.

Comment: No problem, any time bro

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1000, 2000, "number", 5000, 6000, "integers"];
getInt = (arr) => {
  for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arr[i]) === "[object String]") {
      arr.splice(i, 1)
    }
  };
}
getInt(arr)
console.log(arr) // [1000, 2000, 5000, 6000]
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me another method using for loop and splice. Thanks alot. I still have a long road ahead of me before this will all sync in.

Comment: I think the best way to improve the quality of the code is through actual combat. You can do a JS algorithm problem on lintcode or leetcode

Comment: And I usually do this on LintCode, name is SmallTeddy